# c# TabControl won't refresh

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, tabcontrol

I'm writing a WPF desktop application with a TabControl in a single window. I databind some properties in the XAML view and that works fine as long as the values are changed in the constructor of the .cs-file. Changes made later are not shown in the view.

I have 4 Files (that actually do stuff):
**MainWindow.xaml** (shows the TabControl + some Buttons):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>

    <SystemGesture:Double x:Key="FontSize">14</SystemGesture:Double>
    <SystemGesture:Double x:Key="ImageSize">26</SystemGesture:Double>
    <SystemGesture:Double x:Key="MenuButtonSize">30</SystemGesture:Double>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelBooks}">
        <local:ViewBooks/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelFiles}">
        <local:ViewFiles/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelMusic}">
        <local:ViewMusic />
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<TabControl x:Name="TabControlMain" TabStripPlacement="Left" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Screens}"
                    Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundLight}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                    >
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs** (Selects the screen to show and delegates the Menu Comamnd to the ViewModelBooks-object):

```
namespace Bla{
public class MainWindowViewModel { 

    public MainWindowViewModel() {

        MenuCommand = new RelayCommand(o => {
            Debug.WriteLine("Menu Command " + o);
            SwitchBooks(o);
        });            

        SelectedItem = "Bla.ViewModelBooks";           
    }

    private object _selectedItem;
    public object SelectedItem {
        get {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set {
            _selectedItem = value;                
        }
    }

   object[] _screens = new object[] { new ViewModelBooks(), new ViewModelMusic() };

    public object[] Screens {
        get {
            return _screens;
        } 
    }

  public ICommand MenuCommand {
        get; set;
    }

    internal void SwitchBooks(object o) {

        if (o.ToString().Equals("Bla.ViewModelBooks")) {
            ((ViewModelBooks)_screens[0]).SwitchView();
        }
    }
}

 public class CommandViewModel {
        private MainWindowViewModel _viewmodel;

        public CommandViewModel(MainWindowViewModel viewmodel) {

            _viewmodel = viewmodel;

        MenuCommand = new RelayCommand(o => {
                _viewmodel.SwitchBooks(o);
            });
        }

        public ICommand MenuCommand {
            get; set;
        }
        public string Title {
            get;
            private set;
        }
}

public class RelayCommand ...
```

**ViewBooks.xaml** (contains a list of books. Also this TextBlock):

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Bla.ViewBooks"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bla"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="900" d:DesignWidth="900">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModelBooks />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
        <local:Converter x:Key="Converter" />
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="tileView" ItemsSource="{Binding BooksToDisplay}"  Visibility="{Binding IsTile, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
            ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
            MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="{Binding PicUrl}" Width="140" Height="140" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Width="140" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
        <ListView Name="listView" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding BooksToDisplay}" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding IsTile, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Titel" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Author" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Verlag" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Größe" Width="Auto" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
        <ListView Name="blaView" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding IsTileViewColl, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" >
             <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Titel" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View> 
        </ListView>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsTile, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Left" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I tried the TextBlock without all the extra binding-attributes, too.

**ViewModelBooks.cs** (contains the IsTile-Property):

```
namespace Bla {
public class ViewModelBooks : INotifyPropertyChanged { 

    ObservableCollection<Book> _booksToDisplay = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

    FileInfo[] _filesTxt;

    private readonly string folderPath = "/folder"; 

    public ViewModelBooks() {
        Title = "Bücher";
        ImgUrl = "/Resources/ic_map_white_24dp_2x.png";
        _selectedView = "tiles";

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        _filesTxt = di.GetFiles("*.txt");

        foreach (FileInfo file in _filesTxt) {
            try {
                Convert.ToInt32(file.Name.Split('_')[0]);
                _booksToDisplay.Add(new Book(file));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }


    private string _selectedView;

    public void SwitchView() {
        if (_selectedView.Equals("tiles")) {                
            IsTile = true;
        } else {                
            IsTile = false;
        }          
    }

    public string Title {
        get; set;
    }
    public string ImgUrl {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Book> BooksToDisplay {
        get => _booksToDisplay;
        set => _booksToDisplay = value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _isTile;
    public bool IsTile {
        get {
            return _isTile;
        }
        set {
            if (_isTile == value)
                return;
            _isTile = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsTile"));

        }
    }
```

It works as far as that the Menu Command updates IsTile. But the update is never shown in the TextBlock

**EDIT:** Now you can see the complete `ViewBooks.xaml` and `ViewModelBooks.cs`. Actually, 
`ViewmodelBooks.cs` also has this code (with I guess is uninteresting for you):

```
public class Book {

            string _title;
            string _author;
            string _publisher;
               int _version;
            string _url;
            string _thumbMD5;
            string _fileMD5;
            string _areaCode;
            string _length;
            string _picUrl;

            public Book(FileInfo file) {

                string oufName = file.FullName.Remove(file.FullName.Length -4, 4) + ".ouf";
                FileInfo oufFile = new FileInfo(oufName);
                _picUrl = file.FullName.Remove(file.FullName.Length - 4, 4) + ".png";
                //_length = string.Format("{0} KB", oufFile.Length >> 10);
                float lengthInM = (oufFile.Length >> 10) / 1024f;
                _length = lengthInM.ToString("N2") + " MB";

                try {
                    using (StreamReader reader = file.OpenText()) {
                        string line;                    

                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {

                            string[] lineSeg = line.Split(':');
                            switch (lineSeg[0]) {
                                case "Name":
                                    _title = lineSeg[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                                case "Publisher":
                                    _publisher = lineSeg[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                                case "Author":
                                    _author = lineSeg[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                                case "Book Version":
                                    _version = Convert.ToInt32(lineSeg[1].Trim());
                                    break;
                                case "URL":
                                    _url = lineSeg[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                                case "ThumbMD5":
                                    _thumbMD5 = lineSeg[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                                case "FileMD5":
                                    _fileMD5 = lineSeg[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                                case "Book Area Code":
                                    _areaCode = lineSeg[1].Trim();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Debug.WriteLine("ALERT!!! Book-Constructor-Exception: " + e);
                }
            }

            public string Title {
                get => _title;
                set => _title = value;
            }
            public string Author {
                get => _author;
                set => _author = value;
            }
            public string Publisher {
                get => _publisher;
                set => _publisher = value;
            }
            public int Version {
                get => _version;
                set => _version = value;
            }
            public string Url {
                get => _url;
                set => _url = value;
            }
            public string ThumbMD5 {
                get => _thumbMD5;
                set => _thumbMD5 = value;
            }
            public string FileMD5 {
                get => _fileMD5;
                set => _fileMD5 = value;
            }
            public string AreaCode {
                get => _areaCode;
                set => _areaCode = value;
            }
            public string Length {
                get => _length;
                set => _length = value;
            }
            public string PicUrl {
                get => _picUrl;
                set => _picUrl = value;
            }
        }
    }



    class Converter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What changes do you want to appear which are not appearing now ?

Comment: MainWindowViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well. It's clear that if you set the DataContext in your xaml file it is once updated but how should the GUI get notified if your properties are updated?

Comment: "all the extra binding-attributes" are no-ops in your case. You should look them up and find out what they do; this will save you much time in the future.

Comment: Please share the code for `ViewModelBooks.SwitchView()`

Comment: What is most likely happening is your View's `DataContext` isn't the same object as the one your ViewModel is changing. I agree with @EdPlunkett that we probably need to see your code for `ViewModelBooks.SwitchView`, and perhaps a closer look at your `ViewBooks` XAML to see how your bindings are setup.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Tomorrow I will add the source code i forgot. @AnjumSKhan `SwitchView()` changes `IsTile`, but the change is not shown in the GUI.

Comment: The entire content of`ViewBooks` and it's code behind would be nice.

Comment: @linuxrocks Just implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `MainWindowViewModel ` won't help, I tried that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett @Rachel I added the complete code for `ViewModelBooks.cs` and `ViewBooks.xaml`

Comment: Thank you. Get rid of the bit in the books view XAML where you replace the DataContext. Just delete that. That's replacing the viewmodel that the main ViewModel tried to give it. Thus you have two viewmodels and the command is operating on the wrong one. This is what Rachel thought the problem might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem. Delete this in ViewBooks.xaml and you should be fine.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModelBooks />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And here's why that's a problem. You're trying to use ViewBooks to display MainWindowViewModel's copy of ViewModelBooks, created here in MainWindowViewModel:

```
object[] _screens = new object[] { new ViewModelBooks(), new ViewModelMusic() };
```

So you make that `ViewModelBooks` instance the content of a tab. You've created an implicit DataTemplate for ViewModelBooks, which creates a copy of ViewBooks, and it all works. The datatemplate is instantiated **with MainWindowViewModel's copy of `ViewModelBooks` as its DataContext**. It creates an instance of ViewBooks, which ought to inherit its DataContext from the DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelBooks}">
    <local:ViewBooks />
</DataTemplate>
```

So far so good. This is all as it should be.

But then `ViewBooks` creates its own copy of the viewmodel, which replaces the DataContext it should have inherited:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModelBooks />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

So when MainWindowViewModel calls a method on its own copy of ViewModelBooks, you can set a breakpoint and that seems to work, because MainWindowViewModel certainly has a perfectly good copy of ViewModelBooks -- but nothing shows up in the UI, because **you created two copies of ViewModelBooks**, and the one you see in the UI is not the one that MainWindowViewModel owns.

### Extra Credit

By the way, here's a nicer way to create those things in MainWindowViewModel:

```
private ViewModelBooks _vmBooks = new ViewModelBooks();
private ViewModelMusic _vmMusic = new ViewModelMusic();

//  Initialized in constructor
object[] _screens;

public MainWindowViewModel() 
{
    _screens = new object[] { _vmBooks, _vmMusic };

    MenuCommand = new RelayCommand(o => {
        Debug.WriteLine("Menu Command " + o);
        SwitchBooks(o);
    });            

    SelectedItem = "Bla.ViewModelBooks";           
}
```

Then you can use the properties. The problem with `_screens[0]` is that one day you may change the order of the items in `_screens`, and then you'll have to chase down every reference to `_screens` and fix it.

```
    if (o.ToString().Equals("Bla.ViewModelBooks")) 
    {
        //((ViewModelBooks)_screens[0]).SwitchView();

        _vmBooks.SwitchView();
    }
```

Further, I'm not sure where MenuCommand gets its parameter from, but I have a suspicion you could be doing this -- give it a try, after you've made the changes recommended above.

```
    if (o is ViewModelBooks) {
        ((ViewModelBooks)o).SwitchView();
    }
```

Best of all would be to make all your tab viewmodels inherit from the same base class, which has a virtual `SwitchView()` method:

```
if (o is TabViewModelBase)
{
    ((TabViewModelBase)o).SwitchView();
}
```

Then that one case handles every child tab forever, and you never have to look at that piece of code again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch views based on a databound property you can setup two datatemplates like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TilesTemplate">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName"
                                    Width="120"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="http://server/image.png"
                               Width="50" />
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                  Margin="5 5 0 0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And configure a ContentControl's ContentTemplate to switch the DataTemplate accordingly

```
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                    Margin="5"
                    Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{StaticResource TilesTemplate}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=toggle, Path=IsChecked}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource ListTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ed Plunkett had the solution:

> Get rid of the bit in the books view XAML where you replace the DataContext. Just delete that. That's replacing the viewmodel that the main ViewModel tried to give it. Thus you have two viewmodels and the command is operating on the wrong one. This is what Rachel thought the problem might be.

Thanks you guys so much! Also I accept Marius' solution since his way is much more elegant (without mixing view and viewmodel) than my way and I'm taking over hsi idea.

Answer (score -1):

You are using properties and not a DependencyProperty. 
Properties are only used in the constructor. Normal properties do not fire events so the control does not know that ta change has occurred.

Replace Title property with:

```
public string Title
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Title.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(CommandViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: CommandViewModel isn't, and shouldn't be, a `DependencyObject` subclass. It should be a viewmodel, and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Then the Title cannot be updated. However an example here shows that this can be done. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/363568/command-binding-with-events-a-way-from-simple-to-a

Comment: No, `INotifyPropertyChanged` works just fine, and that's how we write viewmodels. It's basic stuff. If you need help making it work, ask a question about it. *"Properties are only used in the constructor"* -- what does that even mean?

Comment: In that CodeProject thing there are no viewmodels with dependency properties. The viewmodels there all implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The only dependency properties are attached properties.